# Avoid duplicates entry in the List - Visualforce page controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

When the user clicks on the checkbox I'm adding that particular item i the `selectedContacts` list the below code works but the problem with that it clears everytime, if i comment the `clear` line then its duplicating the records.

So what is the best way to avoid duplicate?

```
List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>(); 

Public PageReference Selected()
{
    selectedContacts.clear();
    for(accountwrapper  accwrapper : accountList)
    {
         for(ContactWrapper conwrapper : accwrapper.contactset)
         {                
            if(conwrapper.isSelected == true)
            {
                selectedContacts.add(conwrapper.oContact );
            }
         }              
    }        
    return null;
}


public List<Contact> getSelectedContacts() 
{
    if(selectedContacts.size()>0)
    { 
        return selectedContacts;
    } 
    else
    { 
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Simply change the List to a set? Also, why would there be duplicate in the list presented to the user to select, can you get that list down to no duplicates?

Comment: working on a treeview so the user select the checkbox to select all the records or any particular record and can user also select different parent record to select so I like to have non-duplication records in the `selectedContracts` hope this make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely misunderstood your question and posted answer regarding .clear() method.

You should use `Set<Contact>` as suggested by other answers and comments.

But you cannot use this `Set<Contact>` directly in value attribute in VF `<apex:repeat>`, `<apex:pageBlockTable>` and `<apex:dataTable>` because these tags expect List in value attribute.

So you can rewrite your Selected() method like below

```
Public PageReference Selected()
{
    Set<Contact> setSelectedContacts = new Set<Contact>();
    setSelectedContacts.addAll(selectedContacts);
    for(accountwrapper  accwrapper : accountList)
    {
        for(ContactWrapper conwrapper : accwrapper.contactset)
        {                
            if(conwrapper.isSelected == true)
            {
                setSelectedContacts.add(conwrapper.oContact );
            }
        }              
    } 
    selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    selectedContacts.addAll(setSelectedContacts);
    return null;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: still overriding the previous selected item, the point is to keep the previous selected plus any new item select

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into this issue before. I completely avoid the .clear() method now as it seems to clear all previous instances of the list also. To avoid duplicates, see if you can figure out a way to due this with a set. Sets only contain unique values

Answer (score 1):

You can use .......

```
Set<Contact> selectedContacts = new Set<Contact>();
```

instead of

```
List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
```

Comment: Compile Error: Return value must be of type: List<Contact> `public List<Contact> getSelectedContacts() ` getting error

Comment: change ----- public List<Contact> getSelectedContacts()  --to-- public Set<Contact> getSelectedContacts()

Comment: okay after i have changed, now i'm getting this error `Unknown property 'SetValue.size' `

Comment: you didn't mentioned "SetValue.size" anywhere in your, ....... please check if you are trying to getting size of some collection use setValue.size();

Comment: I don't even know where is that coming from but if you look at my question I posted the second method where it's checking the size

Comment: No it is not related to that, this error is "Unknown property"..... find setvalue.size keyword in you code.....